# How do you use texdoc to search for example pdfs?

Tags: documentation

I usually use `texdoc <package>` to quickly access doc files. However, sometimes the doc file is not useful and you want to look to example pdf files. As an example, try `texdoc moderncv`.

Is there a way to quickly access example docs (something like `texdoc moderncv example`)like you do for standard docs?

Comment: there a few examples for moderncv on ctan, but not much in tl, that i can see.  i agree that it's tiresome, but it's not a facility that could be added in a couple of minutes...

Comment: On miktex 2.9 and win 'texdoc --view PACKAGE' takes you straight to the package, 'texdoc PACKAGE' usually opens a webpage listing alternative documentation. I'm not sure if this is true for other distributions ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`texdoc` does not have the capabilities of a "`texexample`" (whatever this might be). Also example PDF's are usually less useful than the TeX code that generated the PDF file. And sometimes the PDF's are not even generated.

Nevertheless you can try option `-l` to find all documentation that `texdoc` is able to find (commands given for linux/bash as example):

```
$ texdoc -l moderncv
 1 [...]/texmf-dist/doc/latex/moderncv/README
   = Readme
 2 [...]/texmf-dist/doc/latex/moderncv/CHANGELOG
 3 [...]/texmf-dist/doc/latex/moderncv/KNOWN_BUGS
```

In this case it does not show any examples, but you get the path to the documentation:

```
$ ls -1p [...]/texmf-dist/doc/latex/moderncv/
CHANGELOG
examples/
KNOWN_BUGS
README
```

And the directory `examples/` is probably what you are looking for:

```
$ ls -1p [...]/texmf-dist/doc/latex/moderncv/examples/
picture.eps
picture.jpg
publications.bib
template_banking_red.pdf
template_casual_orange.pdf
template_classic_green.pdf
template-es.pdf
template-es.tex
template_multibib.pdf
template_oldstyle_grey.pdf
template.tex
template-zh.pdf
template-zh.tex
```